# Can my router provide IP addresses with an internet received via wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

I'm using a borrowed wifi signal from my neighbour, all the devices in my apartment receive IP addresses from his router. Once I was having some connecting problems and I decided to try using what they call **static IP** addresses (big ignorant mistake), all my devices connected right away, but my neighbour came to complain. I fixed the problem, came back to asking the IP addresses via DHCP.

Can I use another router to receive his signal and provide own IP addresses to my devices?

I wish I could have internet in all my six devices but using only one slot in my neighbour's router. I tried enabling the DHCP in my router (normally disabled), it successfully provided own IP addresses to all my devices, but none of them connected to internet. The IP address of my router is 192.168.0.1 (a TP-LINK router), my neighbour's is 192.168.1.1 (a MERCUSYS router) so no chance of conflict in assigned IP addresses.

My router is a TP-LINK model No: TL-WR740N. In this screen t.ly/M-4C my router takes the wifi signal and produce another one. At this point I can manipulate the signal, do some parental control, bandwidth control, etc.

I feel like it should be an easy task, but all my attempts has failed.

Comment: How're you connected to his router? You need 'client mode' to do that - and that's a uncommon thing

Comment: get a so-called travel router (GL.iNet make decent ones for cheap if budget is a concern)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: My router is a TP-LINK model No: TL-WR740N. In this screen  t.ly/M-4C  my router takes the wifi signal and produce another one. At this point I can manipulate the signal, do some parental control, bandwidth control, etc.

I dont think this is so uncommon. What I want to do is positively possible, I've done it already, but I dont remember how, and I can't replicate the process.

Comment: is your router supported by OpenWRT - very easy to make a so-called travel router with that. I think the OpenWRT package you'd want is called travelmate

Comment: @JaromandaX: I dont think I'll use your suggestion to solve this problem, but I want you to know that I find it very very interesting all what I just read about OpenWRT. Thank you for drawing my attention about this topic.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/440/) "WDS bridging" works similarly as Ethernet bridging, i.e., the two wireless network would at least appear to be a single broadcast domain and you are expected to disable the DHCP server and change its LAN IP on the "client" router manually (yeah kinda dumb). I think the real question is what "connecting problems" you were trying to solve. If you are really just trying to "extend" the WiFi signal for a bit, I suppose you can just continue with WDS bridging and follow the instruction in the linked guide.

Comment: Which exact model is your TP-LINK router ?

Comment: You could use your routers as a double NAT(His ISP is already NAT his connection).  Your main router, gets a DHCP address from your neighbor.  Then your router hands out DHCP ip's to your devices.  It should be possible to use static IP, but you can't just use ANY IP there are special ranges like 192.168.0.0/16 and 10.0.0.0/24 and 172. something.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for what's called WISP mode, which stands for
"Wireless Internet Service Provider".

In this mode, a Wireless port of the WiFi router acts as the WAN port,
connecting to a remote Wi-Fi hotspot and sharing this Internet connection
between the client devices connected to it via WiFi and Ethernet.
This mode usually creates a private network, where IP addresses are
are local only to this network and are not seen by the router and
computers in the network supplying the internet connection.

Graphically, this looks like this :

[image]

Reference article :
[What is a WISP on my Wireless Router?](https://wifi-settings.com/wireless-routers/wisp-mode/)

Because I don't know your router's TP-LINK model, this is a summary
of the article
[How to configure the WISP Client Router Mode on the TL-WR710N](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/617/).
As I don't have a TP-LINK router, some of the text below is by
(educated) guess, and might be in error.

- Connect the router to your computer, preferably via cable,
  with no other network or internet connection, reboot the router
  and then the computer
- Open a Web Browser and go to `http://tplinklogin.net` or
  `192.168.0.254`
- Enter user name and password (default `admin`)
- Go to **Quick Setup** and click **Next**
- Select Wireless **WISP Client Router** and click **Next**
- Choose the WAN Connection to your neighbor.
  Your neighbor's preference is **Dynamic IP**.
- Click **Survey**
- Find your neighbor’s SSID and click **Connect**
- Enter the connection parameters for your neighbor and click **Next**
- Click on **Reboot** and wait for it to reach 100%
- Go to the **Status** page and check the information under WAN
  to see whether you have successfully connected to your neighbor.

See the article for more information with screenshots.

Comment: Regardless of model, the parts about PPPoE or "parameters provided by neighbor ISP" do not apply here if OP isn't connecting to their neighbor's _ISP_ – they're trying to connect to their neighbor's _own_ router, which will not be providing PPPoE (and OP is specifically trying to avoid "static IP" as well).

Comment: @user1686: Yes, the word ISP was superfluous - deleted. The "Static IP" part is because that's what the article said, but I'm also doubtful about what it's used for, as the connection to the neighbor is done with Dynamic IP. The poster will have to find out by trial and error, but it might be the router's own IP in the created local network (again just a guess). Hopefully the router's firmware will add more inline help.

Comment: Well, "Static IP" would _work,_ technically, but OP already got told for using it when connecting their other devices, so they likely won't be able to use it when connecting a router as well. (These two options are not something unique to WISP mode, it's the same kind of IP configuration as in a PC, so OP needs to use "Dynamic IP" which is just straight up DHCP client mode.) "PPPoE" on the other hand isn't going to work at all when connecting to a consumer router, except in very rare cases.

Comment: @user1686: Hell's bells, I think I understand now - the article presents two possibilities and I listed both by mistake. The "Dynamic IP" option leads directly to the "Survey" step. So you're right, PPPoE is not involved at all. Thanks for your help - I deleted the superfluous part.

Comment: FROM OP: No "WISP Client Router" option available in this router.

Comment: Your router model was not available when I wrote my answer. You don't have too many options with this router: (1) Install another firmware that has such options, for example [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/) by using its [Client Mode](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless), (2) Get a router that supports WISP.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use your own router to receive your neighbor's WiFi signal and provide an own DHCP-Pool to your devices. However, you need to configure your router properly for it to work correctly.

The way you want to use your router is called "WISP"-Mode.

Normally, at your TP-Link Router-Interface you can just switch at Quick-Setup from "Access Point" to "WISP Client Router", tick "Dynamic IP" and then you can choose the SSID from your neighbour's router.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-KGlVwAFhs

That way, you are not longer using the DHCP-Pool from your neighbour.

Comment: FROM OP: No "WISP Client Router" option available in this router.